# Odoo xmlrpc, You are not allowed to modify on a read operation

Tags: python, acl, xml-rpc, odoo-14, odoo-rpc

I'm trying to use the xmlrpc api of odoo 14.
I have made a small script to do some tests. In the test I do a **read** operation but I get an `xmlrpc.client.Fault` exception, where odoo compains that I try to **modify** `'res.users'` although my query is a **read** on `'res.partner'`

Here is my test script. *(Please note that the error is the same if I try to do a search_read instead of a search then read)*

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import xmlrpc.client

url = <redacted>
base = <redacted>
user = <redacted>
key = <redacted>

try:
    api = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
    mod = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

    print("connection ... ", end='')
    uid = api.authenticate(base, user, key, {})
    print("ok. uid=",uid)

    print("listing partners  ... ", end='')
    partners = mod.execute_kw(base, uid, key, 'res.partner', 'search', [[]])
    print("ok. partners=", partners)

    print("fetching partner ... ", end='')
    res = mod.execute_kw(base, uid, key, 'res.partner', 'read', partners[:1])
    print("ok. partner=", res)
except xmlrpc.client.Fault as e:
    print("error !!!")
    print(str(e))
```

If I run this code I get :

```
connection ... ok. uid= 6
listing partners  ... ok. partners= [3, 15, 7, 10, 8, 9, 14, 13, 12, 11, 1, 16]
fetching partner ... error !!!
<Fault 4: "You are not allowed to modify 'Users' (res.users) records.\n\nThis operation is allowed for the following groups:\n\t- Administration/Access Rights\n\nContact your administrator to request access if necessary.">
```

I don't understand why it's trying to modify anything, since I'm doing a **read**.

Is it because of a computed field in a related model ? With that in mind, I also tried to choose the fields I wanted, and with this example the code works :

```py
    print("fetching partner names ... ", end='')
    res = mod.execute_kw(base, uid, key, 'res.partner', 'read', partners[:1], {'fields': ['name']})
    print("ok. names=", res)
```

Edit:

Please note that this problem show up when logging with a user that has read access, but not write access.

Comment: In your first example, the second parameter of `execute_kw` method should be `uid` not `user`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I actually tested with uid, but I must have messed up the copy-paste from an earlier version of my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with this, what's giving in it.

```
models.execute_kw(base, uid, key, 'res.partner', 'check_access_rights', ['read'], {'raise_exception': False})
```

**Solution**:

When you read any record than all the compute and related fields refresh it's data so I think that will the cause the issue.

Comment: I've put the line just before the read access, but I get the same error.

Comment: I do not, on purpose. I'm sorry that I didn't clear that up in the question.

Comment: Then you have access issue for the particular user with whom you are accessing.

Comment: But it complains about **modifying** res.users when I only make a **read** access on res.partners ?

Comment: Partner is linked with users right? I think It is causing the problem.

Comment: Right but what would be modified when I make a read ? Like a access_date ?

Comment: When you read any record than all the compute and related fields refresh it's data so I think that will the cause the issue.

Comment: That makes sense. If you put that as your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure I have added this solution.